# « Investir » une partie du corps sexuellement

Tags: vocabulaire

Je me demande si le verbe « investir » a un sens proche de « sexualiser » dans l'expression « investir une partie du corps sexuellement », je pense  avoir lu cela dans un texte traitant de Freud. Je vous saurais gré de me donner d'autres exemples de phrases ou ce verbe est employé dans cette acception. Je me demande aussi à quelle définition parmi toutes celles du verbe « investir » données par exemple par le cnrtl (ou dans d'autres dictionnaires) on pourrait rattacher ce sens.

Comment: Incroyable, toujours pas de réaction.

Answer (score 2):

Le verbe investir est utilisé beaucoup en psychanalyse ainsi que les noms *investissement* ou *désinvestissement*.

Pour un quatrième sens,le CNTRL donne:

A. −

> **1. PSYCHANAL. Qqn investit qqc. **Conférer une charge d'énergie psychique à (une activité, un objet, une représentation)**. [L'état de
>   narcissisme primaire absolu] persiste jusqu'au moment où le moi
>   commence à investir libidinalement ses représentations objectales, à
>   transformer en libido objectale la libido narcissique (Freud, Abr.
>   psychanal., trad. par A. Bermann, 1949, p. 10). Beaucoup préfèrent
>   investir leur souffrance, leurs malheurs, leurs ennuis, qui sont les
>   seuls moyens permis par leur névrose de continuer à jouir du sentiment
>   d'exister (A. Bergeds Foulq. 1971, s. v. investissement).**
>
> 2. Qqn investit dans.Mettre son énergie psychique dans. Il a beaucoup investi dans cet enfant, dans sa vie professionnelle (Rob.) Investir
>      dans son travail (Rob.Suppl.1970, Lexis 1975).
>
> − Emploi pronom. réfl. Des expressions comme « Je m'assume » ou « Tu
>   t'investis » et un mot d'argot comme « l'herbe » rempliront de la même
>   nostalgie des millions de septuagénaires (L'Express,30 janv. 1978, p.
>   41, col. 3).
>
> B. − PSYCHOL. Qqn investit qqc. Donner une signification personnelle
>   à, attacher des valeurs affectives à (quelque chose). La « réalité
>   humaine » surgit en tant qu'elle est investie par l'être (Sartre, Être
>   et Néant,1943, p. 53).

[investir, sens 4](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/investir)

**Investir n'est pas sexualizer en soi**. On investit un objet d'une quantité d'énergie psychique.

Voici une définition un peu plus poussée:

investissement

> Ce concept, qui appartient d'abord à la perspective « économique » de
>   l'œuvre freudienne, en ce sens qu'il se réfère à la distribution d'une
>   certaine quantité d'énergie psychique, tire ses racines des
>   conceptions physiques et neurobiologiques de Freud (*Esquisse d'une
>   psychologie scientifique*) pour évoluer avec ses découvertes dans les
>   deux autres domaines, topique et dynamique.

Comment: Quel est le terme anglais utilisé dans ce contexte ? *to attach* ?

Answer (score 1):

Bien qu'il n'ait aucun lien sexuel en soi, il me semble en effet avoir déjà constaté son utilisation dans la description de relations sexuelles. Dans ce cas, je pense qu'on fait référence à la 3ème définition donnée par [le Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/investir/44108?q=investissent#44036):

> Se répandre en un lieu au point de l'occuper ou de paraître l'occuper complètement : *La police a investi tout le quartier.*

On peut donc tout à fait imaginer qu'écrivain  présente une relation sexuelle comme un amant investissant l'intimité (= le vagin) de sa maîtresse.

On pourrait sans doute aussi broder autour de la deuxième définition:

> Encercler une place, une position militaire dont on veut faire le siège en coupant ses communications

Encore une fois avec l'idée de domination, de contrôle, de l'un sur l'autre.

Dans tous les cas l'emploi de ce verbe à ces fins est assez littéraire et emphatique.

Comment: Je vous remercie beaucoup pour  m' avoir donné déjà quelques  lumières sur cette question et vous souhaite une bonne fin de journée. J'espère que d'autres internautes  m'apporteront encore  davantage d'éclaircissements.

Answer (score 1):

Voici un exemple d'utilisation du verbe *investir* appliqué à des parties du corps dans un contexte sexuel ayant trait à la psychanalyse.

> *Dans la conversion, une charge libidinale « isolée », non résolue dans le sexuel, **investit une zone érotisée** autonomisée (surcharge de libido) et l‟affect lié à la représentation refoulée **investit la zone hystérogène**.*
>
> Vincent Gosselin, *[Problématiques(s) des rapports soma/psyché dans les
> neurosciences et dans la psychanalyse : du réel de la
> science au réel du parlêtre](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00651477/document)*, 2011

Le sens est celui de la [deuxième entrée du TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/investi/1):

> **B.-** Au figuré Entourer, cerner de toutes parts. Synonyme *assaillir*, *envahir*.

*Investir* n'a pas de sens intrinsèque relatif à la sexualité, c'est uniquement le contexte qui l'apporte ici. On pourrait lui donner comme autre synonyme *s'emparer*.

Answer (score -3):

"J'ai investi une somme d'argent considérable dans cette entreprise" est une expression correcte.

"Il s'est beaucoup investi dans son travail" est une expression courante, incorrecte et insupportable.